# Layout of an ip header and network programming

Tags: c, struct, raw-sockets

I am taking a class on computer and network security. We are writing a packet spoofer. I could just download one from the internet and use it, but I prefer writing the stuff myself. Below is the struct that I use to represent the ip header which I am [basing off of the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header). I am attempting to send an icmp ping packet. I have done it successfully, but only after assigning the value of the ip header length to the version field, and vice versa. Somehow I have setup my struct wrong, or I am assigning the values wrong, and I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

```
struct ip_header
{
    uint8_t version : 4 // version
        , ihl : 4; // ip header length
    uint8_t dscp : 6 // differentiated services code point
        , ecn : 2; // explicit congestion notification
    uint16_t total_length; // entire packet size in bytes
    uint16_t identification; // a unique identifier
    uint16_t flags : 3 // control and identify fragments
        , frag_offset : 13; // offset of fragment relative to the original
    uint8_t ttl; // how many hops the packet is allowd to travel
    uint8_t protocol; // what protocol is in use
    uint16_t checksum; // value used to determine bad packets
    uint32_t src_ip; // where the packet is form
    uint32_t dest_ip; // where the packet is going
};
```

If I assign the `version` and `ihl`, like below, wireshark reports an error with the header, "Bogus IPV4 version (0, must be 4)".

```
char buffer[1024];
struct ip_header* ip = (struct ip_header*) buffer;
ip->version = 4;
ip->ihl = 5;
```

However, after changing to the following listing, the ICMP request goes through just fine.

```
char buffer[1024];
struct ip_header* ip = (struct ip_header*) buffer;
ip->version = 5;
ip->ihl = 4;
```

I have tried placing `htons` around the numbers, but that doesn't seem to do anything useful. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you aware of "endianess"? Compilers and network encoding do not always agree on the order of e.g. version and ihl. However, usually compilers do disagree consistently, i.e. they would also rearrange src_ip and dest_ip.

Comment: I am. That is why I mentioned the htons function. I also thought that the other numbers would be swapped but hey aren’t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to correct your structure's endianness. Look at the IP header structure defined in the `<netinet/ip.h>` file:

```
  struct iphdr
  {
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    unsigned int ihl:4;
    unsigned int version:4;
#elif __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
    unsigned int version:4;
    unsigned int ihl:4;
#else
# error "Please fix <bits/endian.h>"
#endif
    uint8_t tos;
    uint16_t tot_len;
    uint16_t id;
    uint16_t frag_off;
    uint8_t ttl;
    uint8_t protocol;
    uint16_t check;
    uint32_t saddr;
    uint32_t daddr;
    /*The options start here. */
  };
```

Comment: Ah, I assumed it wouldn't need to be this because the other fields appeared fine in wireshark. Thank you.